# How to remove a link from sitemap.xml in my WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, indexing, seo, sitemap

Rank Math SEO plug-in that we're using has an option to enter Post ID for the pages that need to be excluded from the sitemap.xml. But it doesn't seem to be working.

Is there a standard way to do it?

Comment: you can set that specific page for no follow and no index, robot also you can remove that page from google search console.

Comment: Please share some document on how to do that.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se] and questions about WordPress development and administration should be asked on [wordpress.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it in one of those more appropriate places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your link is in the sitemap.xml and you want to remove the link, please do and check the following steps.

1. Make sure the sitemap.xml is not cached if you  are using any cache plugin, check these [steps](https://rankmath.com/kb/exclude-sitemaps-from-caching/)
2. for excluding the post or page from the Rank Math plugin please follow this [document](https://rankmath.com/kb/configure-sitemaps/#exclude-posts)
3. Also, as I recommended please set the page as no follow, no index by doing these simple [steps](https://rankmath.com/kb/how-to-noindex-urls/)

Comment: Utsav, I tried first two steps without any luck. The link I'm trying to remove is in https://packedwithpurpose.gifts/site-map/. Please search for "faq" and you will see two occurrences for that. Please check and let me know how to remove that.

Comment: @CodeForGood as I have checked your URL these are two [FAQs](https://imgur.com/a/lg6z1cn) ? Do you want to remove from this page that you have mentioned? Also, Have you checked your Rank Math plugin settings?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove from that page. Rank Math settings didn't help.

Comment: which FAQ do you need to remove there are two on the page also I have shown them in the image check my last comment, there is one in the header and another one on page after `Embed Impact Report` !

Comment: I meant one on the page, not in the header.

Comment: just go to the page and comment `<li class="page_item page-item-714"><a href="https://packedwithpurpose.gifts/faq/">FAQ</a></li>` this code and save and check again